# bash: devidion of large repertoire to sub-folders

Tags: bash

I have > 400.000 files in the shared folder

```
mol0.pdb
mol1.pdb
mol2.pdb
...
mol999.pdb
...
mol422222.pdb
```

I need to divide all of this repertoire into 4 equal parts (by the number of the files, assuming that the last part could be alitle bit smaller compared to the rest) and create for each part individual folder (matching the name of the initial folder adding part_N suffix) and copy each part to it. For it I am trying to realize simple bash workflow:

```
#!/bin/bash
home="$PWD"
project='ALL_pdb' # name of the folder with all pdb filles
#############
input="${home}"/"${project}"
output="${home}"/"${project}"_parts # name of the folder with devided files
# format of the inputs
format='pdb'
# 1- devide all filles in the input to the 4 equal parts

# 2- then iterative over the all filles and copy it to the subfolder
for lig in ${input}/*.${format}; do
lig_name=$(basename "$lig" .${format})
# mkdir $output_part_$i
# cp lig $output_part_$i
# etc
done
```

How it would be better to automatize the devizion of the filles and its further transfer to the individual folder?

Comment: What do you mean by "equal" parts? The amount of files (this is not possible because 422222 is not divisible by 4)? The used disk space? ...?

Comment: Exactly by the number of the filles! well it is possible that the last part would be smaller than the rest :-)

Comment: Do you mind if the last part is _bigger_ than the rest?

Comment: well normally the code should work with any number of the input files located in the same folder and try to divide them on several equal parts. I believe it should be better to respect file ID, thus puting mol0-mol100000 in the first folder, mol100000-mol200000 in the second etc. Also it could be logical to difine in the beginning of the script the number of the desired segments (separate parts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will evenly dispatch the files into directories  numbered from `1` to `<number of parts>`. The lower directories might contain 1 more file than the higher ones.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
project=ALL_pdb

files=("$project"/*.pdb)
files_count=${#files[@]}

parts_count=4
parts_sizes=()

leftover=$(( files_count % parts_count ))
min_size=$(( files_count / parts_count )) 
max_size=$(( min_size + 1 ))

p=0
while (( p < leftover ));    do parts_sizes[++p]=$max_size; done
while (( p < parts_count )); do parts_sizes[++p]=$min_size; done

for (( i = 0, p = 1; parts_sizes[p]; i += parts_sizes[p++] ))
do
    d="${project}_part_$p"
    mkdir -p "$d"

    printf '%s\0' "${files[@]:i:parts_sizes[p]}" |
#   xargs -0 mv -t "$d/"       # for GNU
#   xargs -0 -J {} cp {} "$d/" # for BSD
done
```

###### Explanations

Because you're handling a lot of files, you are confronted with two problems:

- Forking a `cp` command per file will be extreeeeeeeeeeemely slow.
- Using a single `cp` command per target directory will fail with an `Argument list too long`.

=> Working around that will require the use of `xargs`.

Now, for deciding which file will go into which directory, the simplest way that I can think of is:

1. loading all the filepaths into a bash array using a glob
2. doing a few calculations for determining the futur size of each directory
3. using parameter expansions on the array variable for getting the slice corresponding to each target directory.